# How to show all other details on new page after clicking row of mat table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular CLI 8.1.0. I have a table in MySQL that having more than 10 columns. On my "vendor-action.html" page I am just fetching 5 columns through REST API from PHP MySQL. Now I want that after clicking particular row remaining 15 columns details of that row should display on a new page "approval" in key-value format. I am able to console the ID of the clicked row on my first page's console. Now how can I display the remaining details of that row on the new page through PHP MySQL and angular?

Here I am attaching my source code:

> vendor-action.component.html

```
<div class="purchases-style">
    <div>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="displayvendors" class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Vendor ID </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="changeColumn">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Change Column </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.changeColumn}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Change Type </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.type}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="timestamp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Timestamp </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.timestamp}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['id','changeColumn','type','timestamp','status']"></tr>
        <tr class="rowhover" (click)="displayData(row.id)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['id','changeColumn','type','timestamp','status']"></tr>
        </table>

         <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" class="mat-elevation-z1">
         </mat-paginator>
     </div>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

> vendor-action.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator} from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { Displayvendor } from './displayvendor';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-vendor-action',
  templateUrl: './vendor-action.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vendor-action.component.css']
})
export class VendorActionComponent {

  displayvendors : any
  constructor(private router:Router,public apiService:ApiService){}
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.apiService.userList().subscribe(displayvendors=> 
      {
        this.displayvendors=displayvendors; 
      });

  }

  displayData(id)
  {
    console.log(id);
    this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-action/approval"]);
  }
}
```

> api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Users } from './users';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Displayvendor } from './adminpanel/home/vendor-action/displayvendor';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private static URL = 'http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/angular_admin/php/index.php';
  constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { }  

  userList(): any
  {
    return this.httpClient.get(ApiService.URL); 
  }  
}
```

> index.html

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","vaamoz@15092018","angdb");

    $request=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    $data=array();
    switch($request)
    {
        case 'GET':
            response(getData());
            break;

        default:
            #code...
            break;
    }

    function getData()
    {
        global $conn;
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from vendor where status='pending' ");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $data[]=array("id"=>$row['id'],"changeColumn"=>$row['changeColumn'],"type"=>$row['type'],"timestamp"=>$row['timestamp'],"status"=>$row['status']);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function response($data)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to get the id of that particular record. then make method in your service

```
getDataById(data) //get specific user data on approval page of vendor
  {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo//php/index.php?id='+data);
  }
```

then make changes in your php to get data according to id

```
function getData()
    {
        global $conn;

        if(@$_GET['id'])
        {
            @$id=$_GET['id'];

            $where="AND id=".$id;
        }
        else
        {
            $id=0;
            $where="";
        }

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from vendor where status='pending' ".$where);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $data[]=array("id"=>$row['id'],"changeColumn"=>$row['changeColumn'],"type"=>$row['type'],"timestamp"=>$row['timestamp'],"status"=>$row['status'],"name"=>$row['name']);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

now make changes in your new component

```
ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.id=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((queryParams:Params)=>{
      let vendorId=this.id;   

      this.apiService.getVendorById(vendorId)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.result = data[0];     
      });
    });
  }
```

on html page

```
{{result?.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with PHP, so I'll answer the Angular part, hopefully, it helps.

first of all when you call `displayData(row.id)`, you should make another trip to the server to fetch the extra information you need.

form what I see here you're just navigating to a local url without the new parameter.
so, if you really need the user to entirely navigate to another page then your code should be:

```
displayData(id) {
   console.log(id);
   this.router.navigate(['/', 'home', 'vendor-action', 'approval', id]);
}
```

assuming you have a routing config like:

```
{ path: 'home/vendor-action/approval/:id', component: ApprovalComponent }
```

then you'll have to retrieve that parameter value from the url and then fetch the data from the server:

approval.component.ts

```
...
//inside the class
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

id: any;
ngOnInit() {
   this.id = route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

   console.warn(`here is your id: ${this.id}`);

  // here you make the other trip to your server
}
```

or another approach to call the service itself from inside your first component and fetch the data asynchronously without navigation:

```
displayData(id) {
   console.log(id);

  //calling api service here

  //then display it on the template conditionally if you want

  //you may also add a loader here if needed.
}
```

sorry for the long answer, again it's according to your question and what I got, maybe I misunderstood it, you may review the answer and ask for more if it was wrong or insufficient.

Comment: Your trick worked fine. Now i made an api which is also retrieving the data according to id like this: http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/AdminStore/angular_admin/php/index.php?id=4

Now i want to create a method in service in which how i can call this path with that "ID" which i am alerting on my target page